# Can't connect to Ubuntu 9.04 server

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, connection, firewall

I have installed Ubuntu 9.04 and am having a problem that I can connect from the server to the outside world but cannot connect to the server.  I checked all of the different firewall systems (firestarter, ufw, iptables, etc.) and all are disabled.  When I try to ssh, ping, etc. to the server they all timeout.

I am running on a wireless network and the router recognizes that the machine is connected to the network (with the proper ip address) but even the router cannot ping the server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure you are using your router's IP address when trying to access an internal node. If you are trying to ping the IP assigned to your server from your router, that is an internal IP (something like 192.168.0.100) and pinging that from outside your router will do nothing, it will try to find the 192.168.0.100 node on the same network you are pinging from.

To ensure access to your server, forward ports in your router to your server. Port 22 must be opened and point towards your server's internal IP address to use SSH.

To find your router's IP address, you can navigate to [WhatIsMyIp.org](http://whatismyip.org) from the server, it will display your router's address on the internet. Your router's administration page should also display this data. When using ping, you will be pinging your router as well, not the server, unless you specify a port that is forwarded to the server, then it will tell you if the node is reachable.

Answer (score 0):

does the router have a firewall? -check the settings there- especially port forwarding. I'd also check if openssh-server is installed.

Also, its HIGHLY unusual to have a server on wireless.